# Why do I get a 500 error when I upload the .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, internal-server-error

When I upload my .htaccess I get a 500 internal error. Why? And do I have to do to solve this problem?

The Content of my .htaccess:

```
# compress all text and html:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml

# Or, compress certain file types by extension:
<Files *.html>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</Files>

<Location />
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
      SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI  \
        \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI  \
        \.(?:exe|t?gz|zip|gz2|sit|rar)$ no-gzip dont-vary
</Location> 

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month 1 days"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 month 1 days"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month 1 days"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month 1 days"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month 1 days"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month 1 days"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month 1 days"
ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 1 seconds"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: If you get a 500 error, you will need to check the Apache error log to see what the actual error was. It could be a missing module, or more likely a syntax error (though I am not spotting a syntax problem here)

Comment: Seeing that you did not even check the error logs (although Apache’s default 500 error message usually tells you that that’s a good place to start), your nickname seems a bit ironic …

Answer (score 0):

You're getting 500 (internal error) because [**`Location Directive`**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#location) isn't allowed in .htaccess. As per the linked official doc:

```
Context:    server config, virtual host
```

Note that no `.htaccess` there in this list.